# How to print a number from a specific row and column

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a 4x2 matrix file:

```
204 4
504 7
204 5
404 8
```

I also have a 4 files named '204', '504', '204' and '404'. So, I want to print the number of the 2nd column in a file inside the corresponding directory.

I want to create a file which contains '4' inside the '204' directory, and so on.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 ways

Substitute LINE_NUMBER and COL_NUMBER by 1, 2, 3...

awk :

```
$>awk '{if(NR==LINE_NUMBER) print $COL_NUMBER}' file.txt.
```

sed :

```
$>sed -n LINE_NUMBER  file.txt | cut -d " " -f COL_NUMBER
```

head & tail :

```
$>head -n LINE_NUMBER file.txt | tail -n + LINE_NUMBER | cut -d " " -f COL_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

`cut -d` lets you specify a delimiter, like a space character.  You could use that to parse your file content (from a `cat` command).

Answer (score 0):

Save your matrix in a file called `file.txt`

```
▶ ll
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 noskillguy  staff    24B May 23 23:41 file.txt
▶ cat file.txt
204 4
504 7
204 5
404 8
```

Execute the below command, for which the above file will be input

```
▶ while read p; do declare -a arr=(`echo $p`); mkdir -p ${arr[1]}; echo ${arr[2]} > ${arr[1]}/${arr[2]}.txt ; done < file.txt
▶ tree
.
├── 204
│   ├── 4.txt
│   └── 5.txt
├── 404
│   └── 8.txt
├── 504
│   └── 7.txt
└── file.txt

3 directories, 5 files
▶ tail */*
==> 204/4.txt <==
4

==> 204/5.txt <==
5

==> 404/8.txt <==
8

==> 504/7.txt <==
7
```

I am reading file.txt line by line and then creating an array for each line `` declare -a arr=(`echo $p`) `` and then using the first object of the array to create a directory `mkdir -p ${arr[1]}` and second object to create a file and its contents `echo ${arr[2]} > ${arr[1]}/${arr[2]}.txt`